# Is it possible Multithreading in Powerbuilder 12.6?

Tags: powerbuilder

> My question is about Can we do **Multithreading** in Powerbuilder 12.6?.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from a [blog post](http://slapouttech.blogspot.com/2010/04/tip-on-multithreading-in-powerbuilder.html) I wrote a long time ago. Don't know if it's still accurate.

> The way you do multithreading in PowerBuilder is to create an object
>   that contains the code you want to run in another thread. You then
>   create an instance of this object as a “shared object”. You also code
>   another object – the “interface object” and pass the shared object a
>   reference to it. You can then call functions on the shared object and
>   have them run in the other thread. The shared object communicates back
>   to the main thread via the interface object.

Comment: Thank yo so much I got it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the SharedObject functions implement multi threading.

Comment: can you please give me an example

Comment: This example requires 12.5 or higher: https://community.appeon.com/index.php/codeexchange/powerbuilder/62-simple-multithreaded-sample#58